# Is it possible to reupload the same version of an app to the App Store Connect?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, release

I uploaded a new build to App Store Connect and started 7-day phased release. Before it was completed, I found out that there is a bug in it. I made a new build and now I want to upload it for a review with the same version number (let's call it 1.20) and only after the review will be completed I want to stop the previous rollout and start a new one.

But when I create a new release, I don't see the new build while it is in TestFlight. I can select only builds for the newer version (let's call it 1.21). What could be the reason of it? Alternatively, should I only upload newer versions of my app by incrementing the version within my build for each new release? In other words should I build my app with version specified as 1.20.1 instead of 1.20 that already exists?

Comment: Do you use build numbers apart from the version number? They exist to distinguish builds in the same release train. Read more on the topic, e.g., here: https://lazarevzubov.medium.com/versioning-in-ios-macos-development-4d03c67b565b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once a version has been approved by Apple and you have released it you cannot submit another build of that version for review.

You can upload a higher build number of that version for TestFlight but you cannot submit it for review and release it.

You will need to upload a higher version - 1.21 - and submit that for review and release it.

In general version numbers don't mean anything to users, so release 1.21 and move on.

Comment: This is standard practice for making minor updates or bug fixes after an app has been approved. When updating your app, you create a new version in App Store Connect using the same app record you created for the original version. This new version will be available for free to customers who purchased a previous version.But you must increment the Build number otherwise you won't be be able to submit. Although it is not stated in the app documentation but it is allowed to do that.

Comment: If a build has been approved, but not released then you can move it to "developer rejected" and upload a new build with a higher build for that version and submit that build for review.  However, once an app version *has been released* as the OP stated they have done, you can no longer submit builds for that version to review. You must move to a higher version number.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, if your previous version is approved (let's say v1.20 with build number '1'), you still upload the newer version with the required changes with the same version 1.20, but you must increase the build number to 2 or higher to upload the newer version. And once you upload, it will show up in the App Connect with the same v1.20 but with different build numbers 1 and 2.

**Note:** Sometimes when you upload the new version to App Connect, it may show up in the TestFlight earlier than the App upload section. You can wait for a while, and ultimately, it will show up here as well.

Comment: This is not correct if version 1.20 has been reviewed, approved and released. You can upload a higher build number for TestFlight purposes but you will not be able to submit it for review.

Comment: @Paulw11 this is standard practice for making minor updates or bug fixes after an app has been approved. When updating your app, you create a new version in App Store Connect using the same app record you created for the original version. This new version will be available for free to customers who purchased a previous version. But you must increment the Build number otherwise you won't be be able to submit.

Comment: Exactly. You have to *create a new version*. Once they have *released 1.20* they cannot submit new builds for that version to review. Build numbers are only relevant within a version. Build numbers must increase within a version, but you can start again at 1 once you move to a new version.